# What is saturated outbound situation? How it could be handled in netty?

Tags: java, netty, outbound

I just found term 'saturated outbound situation' in terms of using netty.io framework and can not find clear definition what does it mean. Could anybody explain what is it? How it could be correctly handled in netty.io framework?

Answer (score 0):

This question is relatively general.  Can you provide more specific context or a scenario?  For example are you asking about general socket (TCP/UDP) saturation, a particular application level protocol implemented by a codec in Netty, or some other topic?

Comment: I need to implement http server using netty.io, which responds on income request to produce json answer. On of the point of task is 'correctly handle saturated outbound situation'

Comment: At what granularity are you saturated? A single channel, your entire NIC, or your transport medium? What does "correctly" mean? - Not crash. - Evenly distribute bandwidth amougnst all channels. - Prioritize resources to certain channels? - Some sort of exponential delay? - Use TCP? Why do you "need" to use netty?

Comment: You know there is a test application that I was asked to develop, in requirements it was mentioned to use netty and there a statement: "correctly handle saturated outbound situation". That is all, that is why I looking for answer how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this indicates the situation where the server is generating more traffic than the Ethernet card can handle.  It isn't unusual for a performance optimized server using NIO on contemporary hardware to be able to generate more than 1Gbit of traffic, and most links you get these days in the data center are 1Gbit.

It is possible your link is for some reason 100 Mbit because the link partner doesn't handle Gbit, and if so that enhances the possibility of this condition.

In this condition threads that are set up to transmit can become blocked where generally they an expect to write a buffer and return.  Smart applications will recognize this condition and log or display an error.   Without knowing more about your setup it is hard to say.

Comment: Setup is simple: netty and simple http server based on it. So I need in terms of netty avoid this situation.